# VirtualHost config run on localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost, fedora

I'm trying to create a virtual host but the config got picked up by localhost address (not by virtual host ServerName, which if I access it, it return ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

[image: desc]

Below is my conf :

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/dev.nanoject1.local.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.dev.nanoject1.local
    ServerAlias dev.nanoject1.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nanoject1.host
</VirtualHost>
```

DocumentRoot point to correct path, permission set to 755, and I've set `/etc/hosts` to :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 dev.nanoject1.local
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Also, there's no error on httpd error_log :

```
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:11.666966 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 124313:tid 124313] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:28.829777 2021] [core:notice] [pid 128017:tid 128017] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:28.831700 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:28.853267 2021] [so:warn] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using [IP]. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:45.042507 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:45.043394 2021] [http2:warn] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:45.051255 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH00489: Apache/2.4.46 (Fedora) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 14 00:03:45.051291 2021] [core:notice] [pid 128017:tid 128017] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Machine is Fedora 32.

Comment: Apache matches your request to a VirtualHost by looking at the IP, port, ServerName - ServerAlias.  You only show one VirtualHost, so Apache has to use that one.  The first one it finds is the default, if no other match the request.

Comment: @Nic3500 So I need to make a default VirtualHost to handle the default request? Doesn't Apache refer to conf/httpd.conf by default, and refer to conf.d/*.conf for other ServerName requests?